# Adding django action to installed app

Tags: python, django

Is there any nice way add custom action to installed app admin? I don't want to subclass admin form. Also i don't want to modify original app code. Maybe contributing to class would work? Is it good in this case?

Comment: Subclassing the model admin seems like the correct approach. Why do you not want to do it this way?

Comment: because i don't have apps created by myself - i don't have admin.py file. It 's not efficient to create app only to subclass one class.

Comment: I would create the app anyway, and not worry about the boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to add custom admin actions, just dealing update with queryset like so:

```
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'age', 'status']
    actions = ['change_name_action']

    def change_name_action(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(status='gold')
    change_published.short_description = 'Change status for selected customers'
```

If you want to use action for any model in admin you can write action as function and add it site-wide like so:

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.add_action(change_name_action)
```

for more advanced usage [read the docst](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/actions/)

Comment: I can do this if i had my app in local project, but i need to add action to installed app admin.

Comment: Tried that, but i need action for one specific model.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, but not sure if it's proper way.

```
def send_newsletter(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        #do stuff

from djangocms_blog.admin import PostAdmin
setattr(PostAdmin, 'actions', [send_newsletter])
```

Comment: Note you don't need `setattr` here. You could do `PostAdmin.actions = [send_newsletter]`